# I only want one dropdown of many of the same class to show, but all are showing

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down navigation where I'm trying to show the drop downs on click. So far, when I click any of the top navigation links, all of the drop downs appear.

I want only the drop down of the link I clicked to appear.

Here is a portion of the HTML:

```
<div class="group group-primary">
<div class="wrapper contain">
<ul class="nav push-left">

<li class="dropdown-control">
<a href="/top link">Top Link 1</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<div class="primary">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/link">
<span>link one</span>
</a>    </li>
<li>
<a href="/link2">
<span>link2</span>
</a>    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>


<li class="dropdown-control">
<a href="/top link">Top Link 2</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<div class="primary">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/link">
<span>link one</span>
</a>    </li>
<li>
<a href="/link2">
 <span>link2</span>
 </a>   </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </li>

 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the code I have to select the drop down and make it appear.

```
<script>
$("li.dropdown-control > a").click( function () {
     this.dropdown = $(".dropdown")
       $(this.dropdown).toggleClass("dropped");  
 });
</script>
```

Since there are many "dropdown" class divs, how do I get only the one for the link i clicked to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure there is a relationship between the elements, so you can tell that they match up. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav">Main Item
        <ul>
            <li>Drop Down Item</li>
            <li>Drop Down Item</li>
            <li>Drop Down Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav">Main Item
        <ul>
            <li>Drop Down Item</li>
            <li>Drop Down Item</li>
            <li>Drop Down Item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use the relationship to just show the related information:

```
$(".nav").click( function () {
    $("ul", this).toggle();
});
```

Here is a [really simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Z27A/).

And as a footnote, you can achieve a similar effect just using CSS:

```
li.nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

li.nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

li.nav:hover ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: couldnt get that to work, I added some of the HTML and more of my script, maybe that will help explain it better

Comment: I added a "dropped" class and am able to use toggleClas like this:    $('#header .nav .dropdown-control .dropdown').toggleClass("dropped" ) But that still turns all dropdowns on and off. I tried $('#header .nav .dropdown-control .dropdown', this).toggleClass("dropped" ) and it didnt work. I still can't seem to target single drop downs...

Comment: i finally got this to work. One last issue I am having, and I notice this in your example too, that both the drop downs can be open at the same time. How do I make it so the other drop down closes when another is opened?